# Just started group theory. Need help with some basic concepts.

Tags: group-theory

I just started learning group theory and I am really insecure with the mathematics. Maybe some of you could take a look at what I have done so far and help me with the questions I don't understand.

---

Consider the set of complex numbers $$G=\{1,i,-1,-i\}$$
togehter with the usual multiplication "$\cdot$".

1. Show that $G$ is a group
2. Calculate all subgroups of $G$. Which are self-conjugate
3. Calculate the factor group of the only non-trivial subgroup. To which group is the factor group equivalent to?
4. Consider $\Bbb Z_n=\{0,1,2,3,...,n-1\}$ with operation $*$ defined as $$i*j=i+j \space \text{mod} \space n$$ Prove that this is a group and show that there is an isomorphism between $G$ and $\Bbb Z_4$.

---

For 1. I checked all the properties (closure property, identity element, inverse element, associative law) and verified that $G$ is a group

For 2. I got two trivial subgroups $N_1=G; N_2=I=\{1\}$ and one non trivial subgroup $\mathcal N=\{1,-1\}$. I need to check which subgroups $\mathcal N$ are self conjugate (normal). I know that a subgroup is self conjugate if $$\forall g \in G, \forall n \in N,gng^{-1} \in N$$

I found that all subgroups are normal but I wasn't sure because it seemed so trivial. Isn't it the case that for all elements of $G$,  $gg^{-1}=1$ and therefore $gng^{-1}$ will always be $\in N$?

For 3. I am not exactly sure I understand what the factor group does but the definition seems to be $G/N=\{ gN:g\in G \}$. So do I just multiply all of the elements of $G$ with all of the elements of $N$? I get $G$ again. Can that be right?

For 4. I don't get the operation. Does it mean that if I take the element $1$ and $2$. The operation is $1+2 \space \text{mod} \space n$. That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: It is not the case that every subgroup of every group is normal. The chain of reasoning that you seem to what to use is $g n g^{-1} = g g^{-1} n = 1 n = n \in N$. But the first step is not valid in all groups. It is valid in all Abelian groups, where you are allowed to commute the group operation. Coincidentally, the examples you are working with are Abelian, so it happens to work out in this case.

Comment: @James Thanks. I knew there had to be something I didn't know

Comment: "*For 4.  I don't get the operation.*" It is like arithmetic on a clock.  Suppose we are working in $\Bbb Z_{12}$.  You have $1+2=3$, $5+6=11$, but if it gets too large wrap around, so $8+9=5$ as well as $10+2=0$ (i.e. nine hours after eight o'clock will be five o'clock).  Taking the analogy to a clock, you might see graphically why $\Bbb Z_4$ and $\{1,i,-1,-i\}$ might work the same way.

Comment: @JMoravitz Aha! I see. I can picture $\Bbb Z_{12}$ but in the set $\Bbb Z_n$ does it mean I wrap around after I pass $n-1$?

Comment: @bluemoon Exactly. The set $\Bbb{Z}_n$ has elements $\lbrace 0, 1, 2, \dots, n-1\rbrace$. If you hit $n$, that is equivalent to $0 \mod n$, so you're back at the front again. Also, just to add to the comment; for $G$ a group with identity $e$, $\lbrace e \rbrace$ and $G$ are always subgroups, so if you have verified that $G$ is a group, you have no need to look for $\lbrace e \rbrace$ and $G$, hence the name _trivial_. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Ed_4434 Cool. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take a look at 3. The factor group (or quotient group as I am more used to calling it) can be kinda difficult to grasp.

We have a group $G$ and a subgroup $N$. For $g\in G$ we write $gN = \{g n : n\in N\}$, this is called the (left) coset of $N$ by $g$ (to get a right coset you do $Ng$, in general $gN \neq Ng$). Lets have a look at an example:
$$ G = \{1,-1,i,-i\},\quad N = \{1,-1\}$$
Check the following: $1N = N$, $-1 N = N$, $i N = -iN = \{i,-i\}$.

More generally when $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $n\in N$ you will always get $nN = N$. Indeed the cosets of $G$ by $N$ partition $G$.

So then $G/N$ is the collection of cosets, in our example: $$G/N =\{ gN : g\in G\} =\{1N,-1N, iN,-iN\}=\{ \{1,-1\},\{i,-i\}\} = \{N,iN\}.$$
When $N$ is normal we can define a group operation *on the cosets* using the operation of $G$ as:$$ (g_1N)(g_2 N) := (g_1g_2)N$$
It would be a good exercise to write out the multiplication table for the operation on $G/N$ for our example, then you just need to find a name for this that you already know.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I was getting so frustrated because I couldn't find a book with a simple example. Your explanation, on the other hand, is very clear and informative. Thank you!

Comment: If you want more practice (which is pertinent to the questions you asked!). Consider $G = \mathbb{Z}$ the integers under addition. Here are some exercises you might find helpful: Show that for every $n$, the set $\{n z : z\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ of integer multiples of $n$ is a (normal) subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. Show that every subgroup of $G$ is of the previous form. Show that if $N$ is the subgroup of multiples of $n$, then $G/N$ is isormorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: Cool! Those will come in handy as practice for my final in July. Thank you very much for putting so much effort into helping a total stranger :)